# how to do nodejs hot deployment in nodeclipse , enide studio, express server?

Tags: node.js, eclipse, express, nodeclipse, enide

I am debugging an application in nodeclispe/ enide studio. I wish to change js files on the go while the express server is running, instead of doing a server restart. HOw can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are debugging an application the best you can do is use the module [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), this module watches your folder for files change when a file changes the application is automatically redeployed.

To install nodemon use this command, install it globally:

> npm install nodemon -g

To execute from CLI you use

> nodemon --debug app.js

PS: Have in mind that when i say redeployed the memory of the process is flushed and do not use nodemon under production environment.